# Как в jQuery удалить оберточный элемент без удаления содержимого?

Tags: jquery

Есть **HTML:**

```
<div id="block">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block_item"></div>
        <div class="block_item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Если размер окна меньше 600px, то внутренние блоки оборачиваются блоком `.block_wrapper`.

```
<div id="block">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block_wrapper">
            <div class="block_item"></div>
            <div class="block_item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Нужно при размере окна больше или равно 600px удалить оберточный элемент.
Как это сделать, не используя `unwrap()`, удаляя элемент по его селектору?
При использовании `unwrap()` постепенно удаляются все родительские элементы 
при постепенном увеличении окна браузера.

Comment: Для этого есть css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
removewrapper = function(){
    var blockwrapper = $('#block .block_wrapper');
    if (blockwrapper.length){
      var content = $(blockwrapper).html();
      var parent = $(blockwrapper).parent();
      $(blockwrapper).remove();
      $(parent).html(content);
  }
}
```

И пример https://jsfiddle.net/qqwdasvb/

Comment: `.html()` - да что ж вы все... `contents` же надо?

Answer (score 2):

Например c `replaceWith`:

```js
var wrap = $('.block_wrapper');

$(window).on('resize', function(){
  
  if($(this).width() >= 600){
    wrap.replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML; });
  }
});
```

```css
.block_wrapper {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block_wrapper">
            <div class="block_item">item</div>
            <div class="block_item">item</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно не класс удалить, а сам оберточный элемент.

Comment: Не `this.innerHTML`, a `$(this).contents()`, вероятно. Не надо портить внутренности.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а чем они портятся? `<div class="block_item">item</div>` в том виде и остаются

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, как минимум, слетают все обработчики, если они не используют всплытие до чего-то выше. Как максимум, повторный парсинг разметки НЕ обязан дать ту же структуру, которая была до этого.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, буду знать!